# Get Anchor html tag by HREF containing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample html code :

```
<a href='javascript:getDetail("Fyk3LqoDuL%2FCwuvERKKP", "czgyagWfgaAx", "VlgmfpBEsUYqKiuKK8S7", "JCVukHdCUy0%3D", "EW4", "C", "N", "false", "N", "TEST", "false", "Daughter", "DEN", "TEST", false, "E335L2T3F");' onclick="s_objectID=&quot;javascript:getDetail(Fyk3LqoDuL%2FCwuvERKKP, czgyagWfgaAx, VlgmfpBEsUYqKiuKK8S7, JCVukHdCUy0_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">Details</a>

<a href='javascript:getDetail("Fyk3LqoDuL%2FCwuvERKKP", "czgyagWfgaAx", "VlgmfpBEsUYqKiuKK8S7", "JCVukHdCUy0%3D", "EW4", "C", "N", "false", "N", "TEST", "false", "Daughter", "DEN", "TEST", false, "E335L2T3D");' onclick="s_objectID=&quot;javascript:getDetail(Fyk3LqoDuL%2FCwuvERKKP, czgyagWfgaAx, VlgmfpBEsUYqKiuKK8S7, JCVukHdCUy0_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">Details</a>
```

The code to look is "E335L2T3D" for the first link and "E335L2T3D" for the second link.

```
console.log($('#sortTable a[href~="E335L2T3B"]'))
```

no results :(

Comment: You're showing only a small fraction of your code.  Where can we see what your actual `href` looks like?

Comment: That value doesn't even exist in code shown and neither does the ID in selector. How is anyone supposed to help troubleshoot when what isn't even valid?

Comment: Could you please before down voting read carefully please? regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *Attribute Contains Word Selector*.

According to the jQuery documentation:

> Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~=”value”] Selects elements that
>   have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word,
>   delimited by spaces.

The strings you are trying to match are not *delimited by spaces*.

You want the *Attribute Contains Selector*:

> Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”] Selects elements that have
>   the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

use `*` instead of `~`, also in the links you provided you have one that ends with a `B`.

`*` will match the following value anywhere in the attribute value.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yb87bm98/)**

```
console.log($('a[href*="E335L2T3D"]').length)
```